# How to access SQLalchemy object in jinja template using column key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, jinja2

I have a table `reference` with columns `id, parent, number, href`, when I want to access a particular row of that table, I pass the query object to the `render_template` method like so:

```
render_template('home.html',\
               ref = db.session.query(reference).filter(reference.parent == 1).all())
```

Now whenever I want to access the first returned row, I use

```
{{ ref[0].href }}
```

What should I do to change the **key** from `0` to the value of say `number` column. I need this to access rows in the template not by their order, but by their column values, I.e.

```
{{ ref['column_value'].href }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load your collection into a dictionary:

```
ref_by_number = dict(
  (row.number, row)
  for row in db.session.query(reference).filter(reference.parent == 1)
)
```

Then you can access what you want using `ref_by_number[number]` (this assumes that the `number` attributes are unique).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems like a legitimate way to achieve my goal, but the added for loop scares me a bit from a performance perspective.

Comment: If you never lookup rows by index, you would replace your current `ref` with this one at no cost. Otherwise you can iterate on the `ref` object directly instead of emitting a new query, which is very cheap.

Comment: I might have gotten this wrong, but are you suggesting that I can replace my current ref var with your suggested dict declaration and not pay any price on the performance?

Comment: Yes, the time it takes to populate either a list (in your `ref`) or a dict (for `ref_by_number`) is negligible compared to fetching the rows from the database and loading the corresponding objects.